# Correct use of buttons in streamlit

Tags: python, streamlit

I'm a new user of streamlit, and I'm surprised by the interaction between two buttons.

Here is a simple example where one button populates the dataframe with arbitrary data, and another button computes the sum of a column in a dataframe. After I generate data using the first button, clicking on the second button resets the data before computing the sum. By contrast, when I edit the dataframe contents manually, these changes are not lost.

Again, I'm surprised that streamlit "cares" whether the list to sum was generated one way or another.

- What am I missing? Why does this behavior make sense?
- What is the simplest way to achieve what I want (first generate data using the first button, then process it using another button)?

MWE:

```py
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'foo': pd.Series([1,2], dtype = 'float'),
    })

if st.button('Generate data'):
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'foo': pd.Series([3,4,5], dtype = 'float'),
        })
    
myinput = st.data_editor(df)

if st.button('Compute sum'):
    st.write(myinput.sum()['foo'])
```